# Turning a browser plugin into an XPI

Tags: macos, npapi, browser-plugin, xpi

I have a very old (1992) browser plugin for a mac that works in several different browsers. However, since Firefox restricted its plugins to XPI files in Firefox 3.6, the plugin no longer works.

I haven't been able to find a useful document describing what I need to do to my plugin to make it an XPI, or at least loadable by firefox, can anyone point me at such a document? or just explain to me what I need to do? I'm using Xcode.

Comment: What's with the downvoting of a 6 month old question with no comment. Sheesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if this is an NPAPI plugin, you can just create a simple XPI (it's a ZIP file):

```
your-plugin.xpi/
  install.rdf
  plugins/
    your-plugin.dylib
```

This follows from the https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Bundles page I linked earlier.

You can create the install.rdf by reading and following the [install.rdf reference page on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests) or just generate a stub extension using something like 
[Extension Wizard](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/extensionwiz/) (here's [a "more official" version on addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder), but I haven't used that) and take the install.rdf from it.

You should probably limit the extension to Mac in your install.rdf (for that you'll have to read the install.rdf reference).

---

[original answer was:] What technology does the plugin use? XPI is a [packaging mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Bundles); the answer to your question depends on whether the technology you use is still supported in Firefox 3.6.

I didn't think there were cross-browser plugin technologies, that worked in 1992 and are still in use now, so it's hard to guess what kind of plugin you're talking about.

Comment: It's an NPAPI plugin. It may not originally have been NPAPI, I wasn't at the company back then...

Comment: @Brian Postow: ok, updated my answer. Out of interested, how was it installed before? By dropping the plugin it to Firefox's plugins folder?

Comment: we dropped the plugin into the /Library/Internet Plug-Ins folder.

Comment: the plugin isn't currently a .dylib... it's a .plugin. Is there a diffrence?

Comment: Ok, so I made the XPI and installed it, but it STILL has no effect... I'm guessing that that wasn't the problem...

Comment: @Brian Postow: Judging from plugins I have installed, it can be a .plugin as well, I copied the dylib thing from the MDC docs. Re: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins - dropping a plugin there is supposed to work, I think. I definitely have some plugins there that do get recognized by Firefox. Perhaps you have a different problem?

Comment: Yes, a plugin can go there, the extension wizard worked fine, so, I'm assuming it's some other problem... but itworks in 3.5.7, just not 3.6... hrm...

Answer (score 1):

Brain; the problem is most likely that in Firefox 3.6 they removed support for XPCOM interfaces on npapi plugins.  you need to use npruntime instead.

http://colonelpanic.net/2010/01/firefox-3-6-has-removed-support-for-xpcom-plugins/

You could also consider using [FireBreath](http://firebreath.googlecode.com) to rewrite it with, as that abstracts a lot of the details.